# Sqlite Returned: error code = 1, msg = no such table: client_table

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to write an application with two activities. Each using a separate table and acquire what is in the table and display it in a list view.

So far the first activity can access the person_table and displays every thing in that table but when I try to launch the client activity I get an error:

```
  sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = no such table: client_table.
```

I need some help

```
package com.rich.myfinal;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

android.util.Log;

public class PersonDataHelper extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG = PersonDataHelper.class.getSimpleName();

    // database configuration
    // if you want the onUpgrade to run then change the database_version
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "mydatabase.db";

    // table configuration
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "person_table";         // Table name
    private static final String TABLE_NAME1 = "client_table";         // Table name
    private static final String PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_ID = "_id";     // a column named "_id" is required for cursor
    private static final String PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_NAME = "person_name";
    private static final String PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_PIN = "person_pin";

    private DatabaseOpenHelper openHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase database;

    // this is a wrapper class. that means, from outside world, anyone will communicate with PersonDatabaseHelper,
    // but under the hood actually DatabaseOpenHelper class will perform database CRUD operations
    public PersonDataHelper(Context aContext) {

        openHelper = new DatabaseOpenHelper(aContext);
        database = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public void insertData (String aPersonName, String aPersonPin) {

        // we are using ContentValues to avoid sql format errors

        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

        contentValues.put(PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_NAME, aPersonName);
        contentValues.put(PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_PIN, aPersonPin);

        database.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
        database.insert(TABLE_NAME1, null, contentValues);
    }

    public Cursor getAllData () {

        String buildSQL = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;

        Log.d(TAG, "getAllData SQL: " + buildSQL);

        return database.rawQuery(buildSQL, null);
    }

    public Cursor getAllDataClient () {

        String buildSQL = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME1;

        Log.d(TAG, "getAllDatayyy SQL: " + buildSQL);

        return database.rawQuery(buildSQL, null);
    }

    // this DatabaseOpenHelper class will actually be used to perform database related operation

    private class DatabaseOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public DatabaseOpenHelper(Context aContext) {
            super(aContext, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
            // Create your tables here

            String buildSQL = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "( " + PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                    PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT, " + PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_PIN + " TEXT )";

            String buildSQL2 = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS" + TABLE_NAME1 + "( " + PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                    PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT, " + PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_PIN + " TEXT )";

            Log.d(TAG, "onCreate SQL: " + buildSQL+buildSQL2);

            sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(buildSQL);
            sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(buildSQL2);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            // Database schema upgrade code goes here

            String buildSQL = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME;
            String buildSQL2 = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME1;

            Log.d(TAG, "onUpgrade SQL: " + buildSQL+buildSQL2);

            sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(buildSQL);       // drop previous table
            sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(buildSQL2);

            onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);               // create the table from the beginning
        }
    }
}
```

The error comes when i call a method in the client activity

```
new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                customAdapter = new CustomCursorAdapter(ClientActivity.this, databaseHelper.getAllDataClient());
                listView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you had an error in the creating sentence (as Gunaseelan said), so the client_table wasn't created. After modifying the creation string you need to call either DatabaseOpenHelper onCreate or onUpgrade functions.

OnCreate is only called **if the database doesn't exist**. If you delete the database, next time you open it it will be created again.

OnUpgrade is called when the database version change. To call it use this:

```
    public DatabaseOpenHelper(Context aContext) {
        super(aContext, DATABASE_NAME, null, 2);
    }
```

As you can see, I changed the database version. This should trigger the onUpgrade function to create the tables again.

Whatever option you use, look at the log to check if there is any error while creating the tables.

Comment: Glad to help! If it solved your problem you should accept the answer so other users with the same problem can easily find the solution.

Comment: got some other problem, both activities are displaying the same content, i dont know the table being used, but the code still remains the same, any idea?

Comment: In your insertData function you are inserting aPersonName and aPersonPin to BOTH tables, that's why both tables have the same content.